# Unity не поянтка в коде

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я хочу чтобы игрок когда двигался в право, смотрел тоже в право, когда в лево, соответственно смотрел также в лево, но он переворачивается только если координат X больше или меньше нуля.

```
public Transform Player;
public float Speed;
private Vector2 moveInput;
private bool facingRight;

private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    mousePos.x = mousePos.x > 7.75f ? 7.75f : mousePos.x;
    mousePos.x = mousePos.x < -7.75f ? -7.75f : mousePos.x;
    Player.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(Player.position, new Vector2(mousePos.x, Player.position.y), Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

private void Update()
{
    moveInput = new Vector2(Player.position.x, Player.position.y);

    if (!facingRight && moveInput.x < 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    else if (facingRight && moveInput.x > 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
}

private void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = Scaler;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Я специально объясню всё подробно.**

*Я не тестировал ни твой код, ни свой код, так что прости, если мой код тебе не поможет...*

В этой строке:

```
moveInput = new Vector2(Player.position.x, Player.position.y);
```

Ты записываешь в переменную `moveInput` позицию игрока.

А потом ты проверяешь кое-что тут:

```
if (!facingRight && moveInput.x < 0)
{
    Flip();
}
else if (facingRight && moveInput.x > 0)
{
    Flip();
}
```

Ты проверяешь где находится игрок. Если он находится слева от центра мира, то ты его поворачиваешь влево, а если он находится справа, то ты поварачиваешь его вправо.

Другими словами это звучит так:

```
Если игрок не смотрит на право и находится слева от центра мира, то 
    перевернуть игрока.
Иначе если игрок смотрит направо и находится справа от центра мира, то
    перевернуть игрока.
```

А тебе надо проверять не проверять где он находится сейчас относительно центра мира, а то, где находится мышка относительно игрока. Если мышка слева от игрока, то игрок поворачивается влево, иначе если мышка справа, то игрок поворачивается вправо.

Ладно, продолжу. Стоит понимать, что в одном скрипте не может выполняться сразу несколько строк и выполняются они сверху вниз. Поэтому мы сначала получаем координаты мыши в `private void OnMouseDrag()`, а потом уже двигаем туда персонажа в  этой же функции. Поэтому мы сначала просто перенесём из `Update()` это:

```
moveInput = new Vector2(Player.position.x, Player.position.y);

if (!facingRight && moveInput.x < 0)
{
    Flip();
}
else if (facingRight && moveInput.x > 0)
{
    Flip();
}
```

В `private void OnMouseDrag()` и у нас получится это:

```
private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    moveInput = new Vector2(Player.position.x, Player.position.y);

    if (!facingRight && moveInput.x < 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    else if (facingRight && moveInput.x > 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    mousePos.x = mousePos.x > 7.75f ? 7.75f : mousePos.x;
    mousePos.x = mousePos.x < -7.75f ? -7.75f : mousePos.x;
    Player.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(Player.position, new Vector2(mousePos.x, Player.position.y), Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Но если мы запустим игру, то ничего не поменяется. Нам надо удалить строку:

```
moveInput = new Vector2(Player.position.x, Player.position.y);
```

из функции `private void OnMouseDrag()`

А так же заменить каждый `moveInput.x` на `mousePos.x`

Вот что у нас получится (готовый код):

```
public Transform Player;
public float Speed;
private Vector2 moveInput;
private bool facingRight;

private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    if (!facingRight && mousePos.x < 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    else if (facingRight && mousePos.x > 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    mousePos.x = mousePos.x > 7.75f ? 7.75f : mousePos.x;
    mousePos.x = mousePos.x < -7.75f ? -7.75f : mousePos.x;
    Player.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(Player.position, new Vector2(mousePos.x, Player.position.y), Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
private void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = Scaler;
}
```

Я убрал Update потому что тут он пока не нужен. Если тебе нужен будет Update, то я думаю ты знаешь как его добавить.

> но он переворачивается только если координат X больше или меньше нуля.

Ты сам в условии такое сделал.

Повторю то, что написал в начале:

> *Я не тестировал ни твой код, ни свой код, так что прости, если мой код тебе не поможет...*

Мне кстати лень перечитывать всё своё сообщение и проверять его на правильность, поэтому пиши комментарий под мой ответ, я может быть на что-то отвечу.

Comment: спасибо, код работает

Comment: заметил то, что он поворачивается только если мышь находить в координатах больше или меньше нуля

Comment: @Александр Кашкавал
Вместо    if (!facingRight && mousePos.x < 0) введи это:    if (!facingRight && mousePos.x < Player.position.x)   А вместо    else if (facingRight && mousePos.x > 0)    введи это:   else if (facingRight && mousePos.x > Player.position.x)   Должно помочь